# Count number of records with same column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

having a employees table with following columns

```
eid    ename    salary    did
100    king     5000      DB
101    kochaar  7000      DB
102    jack     6000      JAVA
103    john     3000      JAVA
104    marry    6000      DB
```

the o/p iz in the form

```
did    count(eid)
DB     3
JAVA   2
DB     3
JAVA   2
DB     3
```

i tried using union all,  i'm not sure, how to achieve tiz o/p.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select  did
,       count(*) over (partition by did)
from    YourTable
```

Comment: i was new to analytical query, but now i got used to it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.did
       , count(t1.*)
from table1 t1
group by t1.did
```